# Delete Query for one record going super slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete one single record from the database.

Code is very simple:

```
    SELECT * FROM database.tablename
    WHERE SerialNbr = x
```

This gives me the one record I'm looking for. It has that SerialNbr plus a number ids that are foreign keys to other tables. I took care of all foreign key constraints to where the next line of the code will start running.

After that the code is followed by:

```
    DELETE FROM tablename
    WHERE SerialNbr = x
```

This should be a relatively simple and quick query I would think. However it has now run for 30 minutes with no results. It isn't yelling about any problems with foreign keys or anything like that, it just is taking a very very long time to process. Is there anything I can do to speed up this process? Or am I just stuck waiting? It seems something is wrong that deleting one single record would take this long.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: But does it eventually delete the row? Is `SerialNbr` always unique? Sounds like you just need a proper index on that one column.

Comment: It's still running. I don't know if it will eventually delete the row or not. SerialNbr is always unique.

Comment: Maybe just cancel the query and try it again. The delete shouldn't be any slower than the select.

Comment: Are there any triggers?, is that column part of an index? (a clustered one, a nonclustered one?), how large is the table?

Comment: @Cory Why?, the delete should absolutely be slower than the `SELECT`, it needs to log, maintain indexes, etc.

Comment: @Lamak: Ok, yes, technically, but not very noticeably.

Comment: There are no triggers. Don't believe it is part of an index. There are roughly 19500 rows in the table.

Comment: @DylanJamesCreighton: 20k rows of the data you've described, with or without indices, would never in and of itself cause the delay. I think you are experiencing the block Aaron described in his answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not taking a long time to delete the row, it's waiting in line for its turn to access the table. This is called blocking, and is a fundamental part of how databases work. Essentially, you can't delete that row if someone else has a lock on it - they may be reading it and want to be sure it doesn't change (or disappear) before they're done, or they may be trying to update it (to an unsatisfactory end, of course, if you wait it out, since once they commit your delete will remove it anyway).

Check the SPID for the window where you're running the query. If you have to, stop the current instance of the query, then run this:

```
SELECT @@SPID;
```

Make note of that number, then try to run the `DELETE` again. While it's sitting there taking forever, check for a blocker in a different query window:

```
SELECT blocking_session_id FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE session_id = <that spid>;
```

Take the number there, and issue something like:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<the blocking session id>);
```

This should give you some idea about what the blocker is doing (you can get other information from `sys.dm_exec_sessions` etc). From there you can decide what you want to do about it - issue `KILL <the spid>;`, wait it out, go ask the person what they're doing, etc.

You may need to repeat this process multiple times, e.g. sometimes a blocking chain can be several sessions deep.

Comment: All right. I'm trying this. Going to need some more permissions from my DBA first but thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: UPDATE: Got the permissions needed and found the block. Got rid of the block and it deleted the record pretty quickly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is there is some kind of performance hunt in the database or that particular table you can see that by simply run `sp_who2` and kill the SP's. Be careful on running the kill sp because it might not be your query.

```
Delete From Database.Tablename
where SerialNbr=x
```